I am using JS and getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: eq is undefined"
function solve(eq){
    console.log(Array.isArray(eq));
    let ops;
    let op;
    let calc;
    while(eq.length>1){
        ops = getOps(eq);
        op  = highestPriority(ops);
        calc = calculate(eq[op[1]],eq[op[1]-1],eq[op[1]+1]);
        eq = reduceExpr(eq,op[1],calc)
    }
    return eq;

The error is triggering on the line: while(eq.length>1){
I checked:
Array.isArray(eq) yields a true log, so it is not that eq does not have a length attribute.
I earlier also used console.log(eq.length) and got 3 (my expected output)
Also checked the element types : all are string type
I have read a few articles on debugging the TypeErrors but none of the solutions seemed relevant previously checked.
For the curious this is a part of a basic calculator exercise I am building.
Anyone have any ideas on what else I can check?

Your error should include a stack trace, showing where solve() was called. It looks like reduceExpr() might be part of the problem, because if it returns undefined your while loop would get exactly the error you're getting.

You were absolutely correct, I was missing a return function in the reduceExpr() function, and that is where the undefined error was arising!
